# Negative scaling mirror alternative Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, rigid-bodies

I am trying to set up an airplane model downloaded from the sketchup warehouse, and in order to mirror the wings (the imported mirror setup had lighting and texture bugs) I have to scale the wings by -1. I want to attach parts of the plane via fixed joints to the fuselage, but when I scale the rigidbody/joint by -1 it freaks out on load. Is there an alternative mirror method or something that needs to be changed on the joints.

If this belongs on another forum (other than unity answers) tell me and I will repost there.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution, in which I put the rigidbody in a gameobject that parented the negatively scaled mesh.